# Problem invoking widget's action method in NopCommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

I am trying to develop a widget in NopCommerce 4.3. I need to Post data from widget public view to the controller's Action method with Ajax. The problem is that when the call is made from the view, Product page is called instead of my widget view. This is the VS output:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 POST https://localhost:44331/aliento-de-ogro application/x-www-form-urlencoded 292298. Excepción producida: 'System.ArgumentException' en System.Private.CoreLib.dll. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executing endpoint 'Nop.Web.Controllers.ProductController.ProductDetails (Nop.Web)' Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Route matched with {action = "ProductDetails", controller = "Product", area = ""}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult ProductDetails(Int32, Int32) on controller Nop.Web.Controllers.ProductController (Nop.Web). Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor: Information: Executing ViewResult, running view ProductTemplate.Simple. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor: Information: Executed ViewResult - view ProductTemplate.Simple executed in 411.9849ms.
```

This is how widget's view looks like:

```
<form id="AjaxForm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="productId" value=@ViewBag.sku />                                
    <input type="hidden" id="input_elem" name="image" />                                
    <div class="col-md-9">                                    
        <div id="ErrorAlert" class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none" role="alert">
            Error en los datos enviados!                                    
        </div>                                    
        <div id="ExitoAlert" class="alert alert-success" style="display:none" role="alert">                                        
            Datos recibidos correctamente!                                    
        </div>
    </div>  
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="SubmitBtn" type="submit">Save photo</button>
</form>

$.ajax({
            type: "post",  // Verbo HTTP
            url: "@Url.Action("TakePhoto", "Photo")",
            dataType: "application/json",
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken: "]').val() },
            data: JSON.stringify(
                {
                    // Datos / Parámetros
                    ProductId: $("#productId").val(),
                    Role: role, //$("#role").val(),
                    ExpressionName: expressionName, //$("#expressionName").val(),
                    Photo: $("#photo").attr('src') 
                    }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            })               
            .done(function (result) {                    
                    alert(result.Message);
                }
            })                
            .fail(function (xhr, status, error) { 
            })               
            .always(function () {
            });
        return false;
        });
```

Asp.net backend is receiving "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" instead of "application/json". Why? Is this the reason because my widget's controller is not reached? Why Nop.Web.Controllers.ProductController.ProductDetails (Nop.Web)' is invoked?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem you're receiving the request from the Ajax call. Instead you're receiving the request from some form in the page.

This seems clear since you're receiving the request from a different endpoint and with a different content type. Since it seems you have an image in your form the multipart request is logical in that scenario.

My suggestions are:

- Check your page and look for a multipart form in it.  Some problem handling events could make that form to fire instead of your code. Are there nested forms?
- Enable the request history in Chrome and the preserve log option.  Get a verbatim copy of the request. Check the Url.
- In .NET, retrieve a verbatim copy of the received request. Check the Url.
- Set a breakpoint in your Javascript code and see if it is being called at all.

I think this will help you.